# Search within two columns for the same value in the textbox

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am having trouble searching for the value of the same textbox within two columns in the database
can any one help me
the code id

```
"SELECT First_Name, Last_Name FROM Table WHERE First_Name Like '%" & Txt_Beneficiary.Text & "%' OR Last_Name Like '%" & Txt_Beneficiary.Text & "%'"
```

Comment: You tell us that you're having trouble but make no effort to describe that trouble. What does the code you have do that you don;t expect or not do that you expect? You need to be specific.

Comment: Please do not concatenate strings to build sql statements. Use parameters to avoid sql injection.